# Reading a private Google spreadsheet using a Python client library

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google spreadsheet that I want to use read through a Google Python client. This spreadsheet is private. Here is the code:

```
import gdata  
import gdata.docs  
import gdata.spreadsheet  
import gdata.spreadsheet.service  
client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()  
client.email = 'xxx.xxx@companyName.com'  
client.password = 'yyyyy'  
client.ProgrammaticLogin()  
spreadsheet_feed = client.GetFeed('http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full')  
first_entry = spreadsheet_feed.entry[0]  
key = first_entry.id.text.rsplit('/')[-1]  
worksheets_feed = client.GetWorksheetsFeed(key)  
for entry in worksheets_feed.entry:  
     print entry.title.text
```

This gives me the following error:

```
    client.ProgrammaticLogin()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\service.py", line 793, in ProgrammaticLogin
    raise BadAuthentication, 'Incorrect username or password'
gdata.service.BadAuthentication: Incorrect username or password
```

Why is it that even though the username/pass are correct and the username is in the company domain but on Google servers?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because of google security protocol. Google doesn't allow any less secure app to connect to your account and these gdata api uses less security measures so if you want to connect to your account using these api's you have to enable to access your account for less secure apps. Go to this link:
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 1):

You can enable an "app specific password" for your program. This is a password that is used only from the program that you are working on. Google's instructions are here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?rd=1, but the gist is that   you should go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords and create a new password.